# Extreme points must have norm $1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a Banach space $X$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_X,$ we say that $x$ is an extreme point of the closed unit ball $B_X$ of $X$ if for any $y,z\in B_X,$ 
$$x = \frac{1}{2}(y+z) \Rightarrow y=z=x.$$

> **Question**: Show that if $x$ is an extreme point of $B_X,$ then $\|x\|_X = 1.$

I suppose that $\|x\|_X<1.$
Then the most natural way to proceed from here is to construct two distinct $y,z\in B_X$ such that 
$$x = \frac{1}{2}(y+z).$$
However, I fail at this step. 
Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\|x\| < 1$. Then $\overline{B}_r(x) \subset B_X$ with $r := 1 - \|x\|$.

Hence, for any fixed $\|\xi\| = 1$ the points $y := x + r\xi$ and $z:= x- r\xi$ belong to $B_X$, and
$$
x = \frac{y + z}{2}\,.
$$

Comment: May I know how to print further with your hint?

Comment: I have added further details.

Comment: So the idea is: obtain the closed unit hall centered at $x$ with radius $1-\|x\|$ so that the unit ball is a subset of $B_1(0)$. Then obtain two points on circumference so that $x$ is the midpoint.

Comment: Yes, right. (The ball $B_r(x)$ is a subset of the unit ball.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider making $y $ and $z $ colinear with $x $, make $y $ a bit closer to the "edge" of the ball and $z $ a bit further away, so that $x $ is the midpoint.

In particular, if $\|x\|_X=\rho \lt 1$, and assuming also $\rho\gt 0$ (the case $\rho=0$ is easy), you can define unit vector $u=\frac {1}{\rho} \cdot x $. Take $y=(\rho+\varepsilon)\cdot u $ and $z=(\rho-\varepsilon)\cdot u $ choosing a small $\varepsilon $ and it is easy to prove that $\frac {1}{2}(y+z)=x $ and that $\|y\|_X=\rho+\varepsilon$ and $\|z\|_X=\rho-\varepsilon$ - both norms at most 1 with small enough $\varepsilon $.